# Select rows where column b is found in column a

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this...

```
------------------------------------
| sku            | superseded_sku  |
------------------------------------
| PartA          | PartC           |
| PartB          | PartC           |
| PartC          | PartD           |
| PartD          |                 |
```

I need to write a query that will show me all rows where an entry from coumn B appears in column A. For example here it would give me the following...

```
------------------------------------
| sku            | superseded_sku  |
------------------------------------
| PartC          | PartD           |
| PartD          |                 |
```

I have tried this...

```
SELECT x.sku, x.superseded_sku FROM table x
JOIN table y ON y.sku = x.sku
WHERE y.superseded_sku = x.sku
```

but it returns nothing and now I don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this query will give you the result:

```
SELECT x.sku, x.superseded_sku FROM table x
JOIN table y ON y.sku = x.superseded_sku
```